# How do I assign numeric values to text in Excel or Numbers and add them

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I created a spreadsheet to track my sons wrestling team.  The text I'm trying to convert is `Wp`, `Wt`, `Wm`, etc. The first letter stands for `Win` and the second letter represents how the match was won.

- p = pin and is 6 team points
- t = technical fall and is 5 team points
- m = major decision and is 4 team points

I found this formula in a prior thread `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:G1,{"A","B","C"})*{1,2,3})` and it seems perfect. Here is the formula I came up with based of the previous;
`=SUM(COUNTIF(C3:C27,{"Wp","Wt","Wm","Wd","Wf","Wbd"})×{6,5,4,3,6,6})`, but I'm getting "*The formula contains a number outside the valid range*" error.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Is that `x` supposed to be a `*`?

Comment: Your formula works for me. Provided the `x` is entered as `*`, it should work. This is an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7). Have you used `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to activate it so it will work?

Comment: It is supposed to be that symbol. I'm not sure how to type that. When I type asterisk it changes it to x. Thanks.

Comment: I tested this =SUM(COUNTIF(D3:D27,{"Wp"})*{6}) this works. As soon as I add more values I get the error message the formula contains a number outside the range.

Comment: @Jason, you may go with Nested IF,,, or if dealing with huge data ten better make table of abbreviation & related points and use any Lookup formula. If wanna to get single value then use, SUM/SUMPRODUCT with COUNIF as show below.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your formula works for others once you replace the `x` with `*` (that may be a system difference but I can't figure it out). It even works *without* entering it as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so that's not the problem, either.

If you're still having trouble, there are other ways to get at the same result. Here are a couple:

1. Use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula instead. It looks fairly similar.

   `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C3:C27,{"Wp","Wt","Wm","Wd","Wf","Wbd"}),{6,5,4,3,6,6}`
2. Add a helper column that shows the score for each match. If you don't want a separate lookup table - it's generally best practice but may be overkill for your application - you can do it all in one formula. Copy / paste what's below and then copy it down for each match.

   `=CHOOSE(MATCH(C3,{"Wp","Wt","Wm","Wd","Wf","Wbd"},0),6,5,4,3,6,6)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I ended up using multiple COUNTIF. It's very long but it works. SUM(COUNTIF(C3:C32,{"Wp*"})×{6})+(COUNTIF(C3:C32,{"Wt*"})×{5})+(COUNTIF(C3:C32,{"Wm*"})×{4})+(COUNTIF(C3:C32,{"Wd*"})×{3})+(COUNTIF(C3:C32,{"Wbd*"})×{6})

Comment: BTW the x's in this long COUNTIF were entered as asterisk, go figure . I will try your suggestions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

*Nothing wrong with you formula, getting expected result for me.*

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C3:C27,{"Wp","Wt","Wm","Wd","Wf","Wbd"})*{6,5,4,3,6,6})
```

- I do believe that you must have using * instead of +.

---

*As an alternative you may try any of these:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `C17`:

  `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$17:A$22=A17),{6,5,4,3,6,6})`
- The simplest is:

  ```
  =IF(A17="Wp",6,IF(A17="Wt",5,IF(A17="Wm",4,IF(A17="Wd",3,IF(A17="Wf",6,IF(A17="Wbd",5,""))))))
  ```
- Use the `SUM` function in cell `C23`, you get `30`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*